# Closing dropdown menu by clicking outside/body

Tags: jquery, html

I've built a set of dropdown menus in CSS and jQuery, but I'm struggling to allow closing any open menus by clicking outside/on the body. I've found existing similar questions that suggest using the `.closest()` method, but I can't seem to get this working:

```
$('body').click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('.dropdown-menu').length === 0) {
        $('.dropdown-menu').hide();
    }
});
```

I've also tried the following:

```
$('body').on('click', function() {
  if ($('.dropdown-menu').is(':visible')) {
    $('.dropdown-menu').hide();
  }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using a purely CSS dropdown menu, or a prebuilt one? It may eliminate the need for this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I detect a click outside an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

Comment: @AlexanderKerchum I tried in pure CSS, but I need the menus to expand on click, not hover. Haven't tried a pre-built solution since this is the last feature I need to implement.

Comment: Perhaps using the `:focus` psuedo-element would be appropriate? Then you aren't sacrificing accessibility either.

Comment: How would I apply that? As I mentioned, I also tried various answers from the related question, which did not work.